# Can't create jasperresponse

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I use netbeans 8.0.2 in windows.

When execute my program in netbeans for create jasperreport, the execution throw this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesMap.readObject(JRPropertiesMap.java:185)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:88)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:232)
>       at PckEtiGotta.PrintEngineModel.imprimirVectorEtiquetes(PrintEngineModel.java:832)
>       at PckEtiGotta.TreballadorSwing.doInBackground(TreballadorSwing.java:193)
>       at PckEtiGotta.TreballadorSwing.doInBackground(TreballadorSwing.java:16)
>       at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My code is more long, but I don't copy all code, I see that the program stop here

```
try{
file = "C:\\example.jasper"
print=JasperFillManager.fillReport(file, map,con);
}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
         throw new EtiGottaException("PrintEngineModel: "+e.getMessage());}
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: please show me map initialization code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem, I explain the solution for others user have same problem.

-Go to: "C:\Program files\Jaspersoft\iReport-x.x.x\ireport\modules\ext"

-Copy this files in "C:\Program files\java\jre1.x.x\lib\ext" and "C:\Program files\java\jdk1.x.x\jre\lib\ext":

```
   •commons-beanutils-x.x
   •commons-collections-x.x
   •commons-digester-x.x
   •commons-javaflow-xxxxxxxx
   •commons-logging-x.x.x
   •jasperreports-x.x.x
   •itext-x.x.x
```